# Spring Roo Date Field with Current Timestamp

Tags: datetime, spring-roo

Most databases allow to have field with current timestamp (act as creation timestamp), for example in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE t (ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

How to achieve this in Spring Roo? Can't find hint from [Roo manual](http://www.springsource.org/roo/guide?w=command-index#command-index-entity-commands).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be created with:

```
field date --fieldName ts --type java.util.Date --persistenceType JPA_TIMESTAMP
```

This will add:

```
 @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

to the field, which should cause the auto-generator to create a TIMESTAMP field. If you want more control, you can always annotate the generated entity field further with

```
 @Column(name="ts", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done as suggested by Simon, but it might be worth checking out a fuller solution.

Check out this Spring Roo Timestamp add-on. It adds 'created' and 'updated' timestamps to all entities marked with its annotation. https://github.com/rcaloras/spring-roo-addon-timestamp

(I created it, happy to answer questions or add additional features)