# How do I automatically set a field in Spring Roo?

Tags: spring-roo

I have an Announcement class that I can access with the standard forms that Roo generates. One of the fields in that class is "time_created". The standard Roo forms ask the user to fill in this information each time an announcement is created. Instead, I'd like to set the time_created field to the current time without asking the user for it. Does Roo support this?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? You can also then change the show.jspx and update.jspx to use read-only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549905/spring-roo-date-field-with-current-timestamp